# Azure M2M Authentication for VUE Dashboard App

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service

I am currently developing a front-/backend solution with VUE and NodeJS. We are authenticating our AAD users without problem. But now I encountered a new problem while developing a dashboard solution, that doesn't have any user interaction at all (runs on multiple tvs somewhere in the company). But I would like to keep the bearer token auth for my backend, so the service can be used with as well as without actual users.

Without user interaction this becomes a M2M case, where the client credential flow should be used (as i understand the microsoft docs). But this would require the client secret to be hard coded within the VUE project, which shouldn't be done at all.

Is there any possibility to fetch a valid bearer token for my backend application without hard coding credentials somewhere? Or are there completely different best practices regarding this type of applciation?

Note: The application will run within our private network with no connection from the public (if that changes anything)

I've implemented the client credential flow within my VUE app, but the client secret needs to be set before build and i don't want to check it into my repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to hard-code your value in the source code you can add your value in Azure Web App Configuration settings and it will be fetched in the runtime.

**Settings:-**

```
TENANT_ID=xxxxxx
CLIENT_ID=xxxxxx
CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxx

AAD_ENDPOINT=https://login.microsoftonline.com/ 
GRAPH_ENDPOINT=https://graph.microsoft.com/
```

[image]

Access the above settings in your Javascript code like below:-

**auth.js:-**

```js
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        authority: process.env.AAD_ENDPOINT + process.env.TENANT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    }
};
```

**`process.env`** will fetch the *Environment variables set in the Azure Web App settings during runtime and authenticate your app.*

One more secure way is to store your Client_Secret in the Azure Key vault as a secret and fetch that secret in your Azure Web App Configuration by adding the setting below:-

```bash
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret/)
```

One alternative is to acquire Token from backend by using Azure AD B2C flow and then call your Web API.

**Reference:-**

[Use Key Vault references - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault)

[Set up OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't put the secret in the app service's configuration since it is created via bicep and therefore it would be also published in a repo. But the solution of fetching a secret from a key vault at runtime seems like the perfect fit :)